# Why does the function that is not exported is executed?

Tags: javascript

The first file contains the following :

```
function func()
{
    console.log("Func");
}

func();

function func1()
{
    console.log("Func1");
}

module.exports.expFunc = func1;
```

The second file has the following:

```
var newFunc = require('./prac');

newFunc.expFunc();
```

The output when the second file is executed is the following:

```
Func
Func1
```

Why is the first function of the second file executed even if the function exported is only the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the file is required, it is parsed and run.  Normally it just declares functions, but since you have a call to `func()` in the code, it executes that call when it is required.  If you remove the call to `func()` in the required file, it will not execute that function.

Comment: Is there any way of exporting the function without calling it in the second file? I don't want to remove the `func()` call in the first file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  Which function do you want to execute?

Comment: I want the output to be `Func1` without altering the code in the first file.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  Why are you calling `func()` in the first file?  Why do you need `func1` in the second file?  It would be easier if you separated `funct1` into its own file and required it into both of the others.

Comment: Thanks...I was just interested in any quick tweak possible...as a similar situation had risen in my code.

Comment: @yobro97 There's nothing magic about `require()`, it just loads the file, which executes everything in it. There's no way to make it skip things like top-level function calls.